# Eclipse 2020-06 - Error The project was not built since its build path is incomplete

Tags: java, eclipse, openjdk-11

I have already read a lot about this error but I can't fix it on my eclipse 2020-06

I installed ide for web and javascript developers and jdk 11.

[image]

[image]

I did some changes to my projects in order to migrate them from java 1.8 to java 11.

I have only some errors to fix.
The first is:
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for javax.xml.rpc.Stub. Fix the build path then try building this project.

The second is:
The type javax.xml.rpc.Stub cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files...

They are related, so I think the problem is the same.
I read that lib has been removed in java 11.
I tried all solutions online but I can't fix it.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

EDIT: I added lib tab as required:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you have in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ in the tab _Libraries_?

Comment: I addedd screenshots of required tab. Thanks

Comment: Unless you're planning to use Java's modularization, the JRE should appear under Classpath, not Modulepath.

Comment: @nitind The system library of Java 9 or higher is always on the modulepath. This cannot be changed since no command line argument exists for that.

Comment: On the contrary, you can both remove it under the modulepath, and then add the Library back to classpath from the Java Build Path property page.